# Header Links showing beyond search box and minicart beyond navigation !! Magento 2.3.5-p1

Tags: mini-cart, toplinks, popup, headerlink, header.panel

When a customer is signed in the header links (My account, My Wish List, SIgn Out) are displayed beyond the search box . See the image attached .[image]

I've noticed that there is an **element.style {z-index:100}** if I change that to 1001 the dropdown is displaying correctly but I can't figure it out where this element.style is coming from . Can somebody point me out where to look for ? Need to mention that this is not happening just in my theme is happening in Luma theme as well . I'm using magento 2.3.5-p1 .

Also I have same problem for minicart. The pop up message when you delete a product from minicart is displayed beyond header. The z-index is 902 and if I change it to a bigger value then is ok.

Is there any javascript or where is this element.style{z-index: 1000 / 902 } coming from .

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing my problems with header . I have installed InstantSearch+ extension and apparently this is the one causing all the issues . I've disabled the module and everything works ok .